# Not getting the right combination using itertools

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, python-itertools

I am trying to use `itertools` to get combination but i am not getting the combinations in the format that i want.

```
import itertools

dict = {(1,):1, (2,):3, (3,):1}
combo = list(itertools.combinations(dict.keys(),2))
print(combo)
```

> Output:

```
[(('1',), ('2',)), (('1',), ('3',)), (('2',), ('3',))]
```

> Output I want:

```
[('1','2',), ('1','3',),('2','3',)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output is expected as your dict keys are tuples. You may try the following:

```
>>> combo = list(itertools.combinations((key[0] for key in dict.keys()), 2))
>>> print(combo)
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

This will extract the first (`[0]`) element from each dict key.